# overflow or garbage value being printed in my sorting program

Tags: c++, sorting

i have a function that takes in a pointer to an int array. the array consists of 6 random numbers ranging from 1-6 (dice game). my function is supposed to sort the numbers in ascending order. i can run my code and it works intended and then i can run it again and i get garbage and or overflow spit out for the sorted output. i cannot pinpoint the location of my logic error, any help would be appreciated.

```
    bool farkle_check(int* dice_roll){
148 //      int farkle1[] = {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6}, farkle2[] = {2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6}, farkle3[] = {2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6};
149         int idk = 0;
150         cout << "before sorting is\n";
151         for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
152                 cout << dice_roll[j];
153         }
154         cout << endl;
155         for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
156                 for(int j = 0; j < 6-i; j++){
157                         if(dice_roll[j] > dice_roll[j+1]){
158                               idk = dice_roll[j];
159                               dice_roll[j] = dice_roll[j+1];
160                               dice_roll[j+1] = idk;
161                               }
162                 }
163         }
164         cout << "after sorting\n";
165         for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
166                 cout << dice_roll[j];
167         }
168
169         cout << endl;
```

here is my sample run, you will notice that the program works as intended for the first run, but then does not for the second. in the green underlined run, it is also worth noting that the last 5 numbers outputted are indeed 5 of my original random numbers and they are sorted. not sure what is the cause for the first random garbage numbers though.

[image]

Comment: `dice_roll[j+1]` is going to access the array out of bounds -> *undefined behavior*

Comment: Why are you not just using [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i cant use c++ 11 which is where the sort() function is.

Comment: `std::sort` has existed long before C++11

Comment: @UnholySheep so in my conditional, have a check that dice_roll[j+1] is still in the array? how would one do this, can i check if dice_roll[j+1] position is less than 6?

Comment: does sort only work with vectors? or can i use it with 6 integers or an array of integers?

Comment: Have you tried `std::sort(dice_roll, dice_roll + 6);`? Though using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays is prefereable in any case

Comment: @UnholySheep i cant use vectors at the moment, how do you print out the result of the sort() function? cout << sort() did not work. also in my for loops, how would i solve the out of bounds problem? thank you for your help.

Comment: `sort()` sorts the array that you used as the argument. It returns nothing. Call sort like how UnholySheep showed it and then print out the array `dice_roll` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You're facing the famous 'index out of bound' error. Your sorting loops are exceeding the array bounds resulting reading/writing violation. As short, check the array bounds and make sure you're not violating any memory address.

Comment: i cannot find the memory address violation. let me continue testing, thank you for your help

Comment: In the loop after cout, for i = 0 the inner loop index j exceeds the length of the array. ( i= 0 and j=5 you are accessing dice_roll[6]. That's where the violation occurs.)